# How and how much comments will impact on application performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, comments

I created a small Ruby on Rails 3 application. In my file I have commented a lot of code that serves to document in detail each method. The documentation for each file is about a quarter of the entire file.

**How** and **how much** this will impact on *application performance*? Running the production environments (maybe compiling the application), comments will be evaluated on loading files or on loading them will be completely ignored without effects on performance?

Comment: In my opinion one shouldn't bather himself with this kind of questions, having clean and clear code is such an advantage that no performance problem will discourage you from doing it. - The rule should be: make it good, make it clear. Then, when and IF you have performance problems, understand where the bottle neck is and act just there. That said my guess is that the answer will be no difference in performance

Comment: Compared to latency on the network between you and the database or your customers/clients browsers and your app, the extra time to ignore the comments in the code are not worth worrying about. If you are that concerned, then run a couple million [Benchmark](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/benchmark/1.9.2/frames) loops and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect will be essentially zero performance difference. One could argue that evaluating comments is marginally slower, but the effect on the maintainability and readability of your code will be so great that no amount of shaving microseconds of time off Ruby's evaluation could be worth it.

In production, your objects should be evaluated once and cached if you have the `cache_classes` settings specified in your `config/environments/production.rb` file (you should - it's the default):

```
# The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.    
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true
```

Way to comment thoroughly! Future-You will thank Past-You for it.

Comment: "Future-You will thank Past-You for it": I know and will know.

Comment: since ruby is interpreted, the files need to be read in at runtime... If you have a very large number of comments, this will actually slow down the app as each syscall will need to read the comments. Comments could be stripped when building or before deploying code. I don't have benchmarks to back up this theory.

Answer (score 5):

*Pray* that you are so successful that you must trim back your comments.

Comment: Pray that we're all that successful. Hilar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers might be missing the point. In a different environment I've maintained the development version of code (fully commented); and the implementation process migrated the code, but not the comments (for the sake of performance). If you are confident of your implementation procedure you can thus have the best of both worlds.

Not answering the question, but clarifying what would be ideal - no overhead in production, but still fully commented code.

And as has been said - never scrimp on comments. Rather too much than too little.

Comment: Disagree. The question is "Will this impact application performance?" and the answers are "No, not in any measurable way", not "How can I easily remove comments for a production site?"